# Django DetailView not displaying the content from the database

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to develop a job portal where people can post jobs. I created a Listview and a DetailView for the application. The list view is working but the content isn't appearing on the details page.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Application_create
# Create your views here.

class AllApps(ListView):
    model = Application_create
    template_name = 'fundamentals/allapps.html'
    ordering = ['-id']

class ApplicationInDetail(DetailView):
    model = Application_create
    template_name = 'fundamentals/application_detail.html'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import AllApps, ApplicationInDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path('allappslist', AllApps.as_view(), name='applist'),
   path('app_in_detail/<int:pk>', ApplicationInDetail.as_view(), name='application_detail')
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

# Create your models here.
class Application_create(models.Model):
    application_title = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    application_opening = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    application_closing = models.DateField()
    application_description = models.TextField(default='')
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    skills_req = models.CharField(max_length=2000, default='')
    job_pay = models.IntegerField(default=10000)
    freelancing_pay = models.IntegerField(default=10000)
    job_type = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.application_title + self.company_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('application_detail', args = [str(self.id)])
```

base.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
      {% load static %}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/allappslist.css' %}">        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar_custom">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="{% static 'images/expertoblogo.png' %}" width="40" height="40" alt="">
          </a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" >EXPERTOB</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="background-color: white;">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                
                <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right: 15px;">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right: 15px;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right: 15px;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
          </nav>

           {% block content %}

           {% endblock %}

           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

allapps.html:

```
{% extends 'fundamentals/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for app in object_list %}
<ul>
    <li class="list-group-item  app_title" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right:30px; margin-top: 30px; background-color:  #007FFF;">
        
       <span style="color:white;"> {{app.application_title}} </span> 

     </li>
    

     <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right:30px;">
        
        <p>Company name: <span style="font-weight: bold;">{{app.company_name}} </span> </p>
      
      </li>


     <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right:30px;">
        
      <p>  {{app.application_description | slice:"0:200"}} .......  </p>

      <p>  <a href="{% url 'application_detail' app.pk %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button> </a> </p>
    
    </li>
    

</ul>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

application_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'fundamentals/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1> {{app.company_name}} </h1>

{% endblock %}
```

I've specified the model in views too but the content isn't appearing in the application_detail.html file. I'm using a mongo database which is working as the content is appearing in the allapps.html file. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

I think you must add `context_object_name`, change your code like below

```
class ApplicationInDetail(DetailView):
    model = Application_create
    template_name = 'fundamentals/application_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'app'
```

Comment: I have a similar idea used before, it worked fine there! Can u tell why this difference occurs?

Comment: DetailView class has a method ([link](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/#get_context_data)) this method uses your context_object_name you define in your view or use your model name because 'app' is not your model name and not defined in your view there is not any 'app' variable in your template

Answer (score 0):

In your list view you have `{% for app in object_list %}`.
`object_list` is Django's default naming of the list of objects in your view.

In your detail view you use `app`, but this should be `object` as that is Django's default naming of the object in the detail view.

The documentation is here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: Or add context_object_name like Reza answered.